# What is difference between ActivityRetainedComponent @ActivityRetainedScope and ActivityComponent @ActivityScoped in dagger hilt android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

[image]
What is difference between ActivityRetainedComponent @ActivityRetainedScope and ActivityComponent    @ActivityScoped in dagger hilt android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the [documents](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components). `ActivityRetainedComponent` lives across configuration changes, so it is created at the first onCreate and last onDestroy, and when you mark your dependencies in `ActivityRetainedComponent` with `@ActivityRetainedScope` its guarantees that your object will be a singleton and survive across configuration changes. But `ActivityComponent` created at `onCreate` and destroyed at `onDestroy`. and when you mark your dependencies in `ActivityComponent` with `@ActivityScope` its guarantees that your object will be a singleton but `ActivityComponent` will be destroyed in configuration changes.

Comment: First onCreate and last onDestroy of what? The Application? The Activity in question? Any Activity in the app?

Comment: First onCreate and last onDestroy of your activity that uses hilt for dependency injection.

Comment: What the difference then with @ViewModelScope?

Comment: Here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765298/hilt-why-is-activityretainedscoped-vs-viewmodelscoped) you can read more about the difference between these two scopes. (ViewModelScoped vs ActivityRetainedScoped). @AlexanderSkvortsov

Answer (score 4):

`@ActivityRetainedScope` will safe guard from configuration changes such screen orientation or language changes.